# Efficient way to Display over 10K records

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a need to display over 10K records in a rich text box. when all loaded I ran out of memory. How can I load those records in 50+ records and also able to scroll .

Thanks

Comment: Can you try compiling as a 64-bit application?

Comment: More often than not, if you're trying to load 10K records into a rich text box, you've got bigger problems than running out of memory.  What will the user expect (or be expected) to do with so much data?

Comment: If you have a need to display 10K records, you're doing something wrong. :) You need to be filtering what you're displaying to something a user can actually view. You probably should spend some time re-thinking your design.

Answer (score 5):

Don't.

Even if you implemented something like Infinite Scrolling for the Rich Text Box, it'd be unusable. There has to be a better interaction method for displaying those records than a Rich Text Box.

I would suggest creating another question that explained what you were trying to achieve and asking for UI/UX suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming just holding the rtf for 10k records is no problem and that the richtext control itself is eating up your memory trying to allocate a giant graphical surface or something. Implement in-memory paging and just assign the .rtf property of the control some subset of records. You can use a prev/next page buttons or a scrollbar or whatever you want.